# Why should I use 'used' not 'use'?

Tags: word-choice

I often see this phrase:
'It can be **used** for...'

But why is it not:
'It can be **use** for...'?

Even though it is still can be used presently?
Is it because of the word 'be'?

Comment: "used" is passive. Has nothing to do with past/present.

Comment: _Used_ is not passive; _used_ is the past participle of the verb _use_ (it's also the past tense, because _use_ is a regular verb). The past participle is the verb form that  appears, with auxiliary verbs, in the passive and the perfect constructions, among others.

Comment: "You/one can use it for.." and "It can be used..." are both correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This construction (or verb-chain, or verb-group—we don't have a consistent name for it) is a modal passive.

Only on the first verb in the group is *finite*—having a specific past or non-past reference.; subsequent verbs must be non-finite forms.

A modal verb is always first, and always finite:

> **can**

The verb immediately following a modal always takes the infinitive form, unmarked with *to*. The infinitive form of *BE* is *be*, so

> can **be**

The passive is constructed from a form of *BE* followed by a past participle form. *Use* is a regular verb, so its past participle form is identical with its past form, *used*.

> can be **used**.

Answer (score 0):

The "used" of "it can be used" is not a past tense form, despite it being called a "past participle".  Instead, it is a passive verb form, which is usually the same as the past form.  The term "past participle" is a confusing and unwise piece of terminology, but it's traditional, and we're stuck with it.  Sorry.  It ought to be called a "passive participle".

Comment: I agree that the name is unfortunate, but "passive participle" isn't much better--it doesn't describe use in the perfect construction or the (admittedly rare) use as an active adjectival: *learned*, *travelled*.

Comment: @StoneyB Huh?  The passive participle is not used in the perfect construction, any more than it's used as a past tense.  And none of these is an adjective.

Comment: Are you proposing that English verbs have three participles with identical form? --a perfect participle (*He has broken his leg*), a passive participle (*His leg was broken when he fell*) and an adjectival participle (*He was treated for a broken leg*). I'll buy that, though I'd rather say there's just one participle with three uses.